# How to update data in google app engine - Python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

How do i update my records in google app engine?

I have my model with the following fields

```
doc_no = db.IntegerProperty()
title = db.StringProperty()
level = db.StringProperty()
```

What i want is to update the fields title and level, but i want to access the properties/attributes via a string like JavaScript objects i.e

if i do a select to the model

```
myRecord = db.GQLQuery('Select * from MyModelAbove where doc_no = 1')
```

Is it possible to access and update the properties like this;

```
myRecord['title']='New Tile'
myRecord['level']='Level2'
myRecord.put()
```

The one i have seen is this(not working for me);

```
myRecord.title = 'New Title'
```

NB: By the way google documentation is very scanty on this area

Comment: In what way is `myRecord.title = 'New Title'` not working? (For dealing with properties given a string name, look into `setattr` and `getattr`, although unless you're being passed in the attribute names as strings from other code, this generally starts to look ugly.

Comment: It's also a code smell that you might be doing something very dangerous, like letting users control what fields are read and written directly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your code sample, myRecords is a query. You must [get](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlqueryclass#GqlQuery_get) the result before any modification:

```
result = myRecords.get()
```

Then, if you can't or don't want to access the title property with `result.title`, you could use `setattr(result, 'title', 'New Title')` then `result.put()`